# How can I skip hidden windows when using FindWindow()?

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I create a window without showing it:

```
int main()
{
    CreateWindow("SysListView32","Geek",0, 0, 0, 0, 0,NULL, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetCurrentProcess(), NULL);

    getch();
}
```

...and in another process use [`FindWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499.aspx) to find its handle:

```
int main()
{
    HWND H = FindWindow("SysListView32", "Geek");
    std::cout<< "The handle of created window is : " <<H;

    getch();
}
```

How is `FindWindow` finding its handle? I assumed it would *not* find it, because process1 is not showing the window.

How can I find only *visible* windows?

Answer (score 6):

Even if a window is not visible, it is of course in the list of all existing windows that FindWindow enumerates (you can display this list using Spy++ for example). If you do not want to search for hidden windows, you have to check their flags:

```
HWND H = FindWindow("SysListView32", "Geek");
if (H)  {
  LONG style = GetWindowLong(H, GWL_STYLE);
  if (style & WS_VISIBLE)
    std::cout << "The handle of created visible window is : " << H << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "The handle of created hidden window is : " << H << std::endl;
} else {
  std::cout << "No such window found" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FindWindow finds top-level windows.

While your CreateWindow call is creating a top-level window (i.e. one with no parent) I'm not convinced it will actually work.

It's certainly very unusual (if not wrong) to create a top-level SysListView32. ListView controls should be the children of top-level windows, not top-level windows in their own right.

Comment: Unusual perhaps but I don't think there's anything wrong with it. Windows doesn't care what kind of window you use for the top level.